pytest - argument missing when using parametrize
I have a list of dictionaries non_metric_cases which are the test cases i want to run using the below code:
class TestEntityExtractionNonMetricFlow(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def asyncSetUp(self) -> None:
        self.llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
            openai_api_type="azure",
            deployment_name=llm_resource.deployment,
            model=llm_resource.model,
            azure_endpoint=llm_resource.azure_api_base,
            openai_api_key=llm_resource.azure_api_key,
            openai_api_version=llm_resource.azure_api_version,
            temperature=0,
            streaming=False,
        )

    async def asyncTearDown(self) -> AzureChatOpenAI:
        del self.llm

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("case", non_metric_cases, ids=[case["test_name"] for case in non_metric_cases])
    async def test_non_metric_cases(self, case: dict):
        # Process the query
        actual_entities = await get_query_datapoint_filters_non_metric(user_query=case['query'], llm=self.llm)

        # Assert that the actual entities match the expected entities
        assert actual_entities == case["expected_entities"], f"Failed for test case: {case['test_name']}"

But this gives the following error :
TestEntityExtractionNonMetricFlow::test_non_metric_cases - TypeError: test_non_metric_cases() missing 1 required positional argument: 'case'

Couldn't find the mistake.
It seemed like i am not passing any argument like "case", but that is not true.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example (MRE). As it it it is impossible to run your code to test where the issue occurs and why.
